# How to Convert below Line in Page Object using Protractor

Tags: protractor

want to convert below line

```
rows.element(by.xpath(".//*[@ng-model='strategy.COMMENT']")).clear()
```

into page object like

```
rows.dataCatcherPage.strategyAUMValue.clear()
```

But i am getting the error

> "Failed: Cannot read property 'strategyAUMValue' of undefined"

This is the Page object

```
strategyAUMValue: {
    get: function () {
        return element(by.xpath(".//*[@ng-model='strategy.AUM_VALUE']"));
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

page

```
module.exports = new function () {
    var elements : {
        strategyAUMValue : element(by.xpath(".//*[@ng-model='strategy.AUM_VALUE']"))
    };

    this.clear = {
        strategyAUMValue : elements.strategyAUMValue.clear()
    };

    this.getText = {
        strategyAUMValue : elements.strategyAUMValue.getText()
    };
};
```

spec

```
var dataCacherPage = require('./dataCacher.page.js');

describe('Data cacher', function(){
    it('can clear the strategy aum value', function(){
        dataCacherPage.clear.strategyAUMValue();
        expect(dataCacherPage.clear.strategyAUMValue()).toEqual('', 'Strategy AUM Value should have been an empty string');
    });
});
```

This lets your page elements be private(separating your framework layers), but gives you full access to all of the actions a test would be taking. You can expand on it by adding any other elements to the elements section, then adding to any this.clear/getText/isDisplayed type function that the element will need for testing.

Some extensibility:

```
module.exports = new function () {
    var elements : {
        strategyAUMValue : element(by.xpath(".//*[@ng-model='strategy.AUM_VALUE']")),
        // Get an element where multiple exist
        coolElement : $$('[name="coolElement"]')
    };

    this.clear = {
        strategyAUMValue : elements.strategyAUMValue.clear()
    };

    this.getText = {
        strategyAUMValue : elements.strategyAUMValue.getText(),
        coolElement : elements.coolElement.getText()
    };
};
```

.

```
var dataCacherPage = require('./dataCacher.page.js');

describe('Data cacher', function(){
    it('can hit multiple elements', function(){
        // Just add an index on coolElement to get whichever you want
        expect(dataCacherPage.clear.coolElement(2)).toEqual('This is the third cool element on the page', 'Should have gotten the text from the third cool element');
    });
});
```

Comment: There is a repeater in it..and i am iterating each row...
this is the page object created above...but i want the page object for each row and not individually.....